# I want to prove that there is a group $G$ of order $p^{3}$ satisfying $|a|=p^{2},\,|b|=p \,and\, b^{-1}ab=a^{1+p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime.Now I have $|a|=p^{2}$ and $|b|=p$.

I want to prove that there is a group $G$ of order $p^{3}$ satisfying

$$|a|=p^{2},\,|b|=p \,and\, b^{-1}ab=a^{1+p}$$

Here's my attempt:

Let $G$ be an order of $p^3$.
$G$ is finite nilpotent and $\langle a\rangle$ is maximal proper subgroup of $G$. 
Then $\langle a\rangle\unlhd G. $Hence $b^{-1}ab\in\langle a\rangle$

But I fail to conclude that $b^{-1}ab=a^{1+p}$

Any valuable suggestion will be the greatest appreciated. Thanks for patient reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to construct this group as a semi-direct product. Define $C_{p^2}\rtimes_\phi C_p$.  $\text{Aut}(C_{p^2})\cong C_{p^2}^\times$, so just map from $C_p$ to $C_{p^2}^\times$ by sending $1\rightarrow 1+p$ (you can check that this defines a group operation). Then identifying $(1,0)$ with $a$, and $(0,1)$ with $b$, we see that $(0,1)\cdot(1,0)\cdot(0,1)^{-1}=(1+p,0)$, so this is such a group. The real issue is showing that any non-abelian group of order $p^3$ has this sort of behavior.